# Home cinema: Convert HDMI to HDMI + Audio

Tags: television

I have the following devices:

1. Projector [HDMI]
2. Sub Woofer [Stereo Audio]
3. Media Center [HDMI]

I need to split the output of the Media Center into HDMI for the Projector and Stereo Audio for the Sub Woofer.

Research I make on the subject seems to always lead to VGA plugs, which I do not want.

What would an example adapter / splitter be for this kind of scenario?

Additional information:

I am aware that HDMI contains Audio, my intention is to take the Audio out of the HDMI (if that makes sense) and send it through a different type of cable so my Sub Woofer can use it. The setup I have used to work great, I had an XBox with a separate output for Audio. However, that died on me, so I am replacing it with this other device.

What I am intending to do:

[image: http://i.imgur.com/775pKOs.png]

I am very open to changing the wiring, if need be!

My Sub Woofer:

[image]

My Media Center - A tiny Android device with an HDMI IN and HDMI OUT port, but no separate audio output:

[image]

My Projector - lots of input for audio / etc, however it uses inbuilt speakers in the Projector which are terrible quality:

[image]

Comment: Got a picture of the back of your media center? FWIW, HDMI includes audio.

Comment: Your Sub Woofer is Stereo? That seems very unlikely. What is a "Media Center" do you mean a PC? A Receiver?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many devices out there that will do this. Just do a google search for 'HDMI audio splitter'.  You will find your choice of HDMI switchs (2-4 inputs, 1 output) that will extract audio and a lot of these boxes will auto switch the input to the one that is on.  You will also find boxes with a single HDMI input/output that will extract audio as well.  Usually the audio extraction will be toslink (optical), spdif (digital RCA).  Some will include decoders and output analog stereo.

Here is an example on amazon.  [http://www.amazon.com/ViewHD-Extractor-Optical-Converter-VHD-H2HSAs/dp/B00KBHX072](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00KBHX072)

Comment: Audio *extractor*. That was the keyword I was missing. I knew an adapter like that must exist. I think this is what I need.

Answer (score 1):

HDMI includes audio in it's signal.  Splitting off the audio isn't very hard, but recombining is, so most systems use one of two methods:

- Some audio equipment has HDMI inputs and outputs.  These pass through the video to your projector and do the audio themselves.
- Many (most?) projectors and TVs that have an HDMI input also have an audio output, either a headphone jack or optical output, that can be hooked up to your sound system.  This will pass the HDMI audio to the speakers.